# Running a .bat file from R - had status 2

Tags: r, batch-file

I am trying to run a .bat file, which does run perfectly when I double click in it (Windows OS), but fails when I try to run it in R

```
 com <- "C:\\SASLocal\\RUN3614\\56a8c11b-84b2-4af7-a155-01190936b1c1\\M1_superGOtest.bat"

 system(com)
```

I am getting back a message of `had status 2`

Just an FYI, this triggers a SAS program, which I need to run in SAS as it is for comparison purposes between SAS and R.

Comment: Sounds like a warning rather than an error: `?system` - "*If command runs but gives a non-zero exit status this will be reported with a warning and in the attribute "status" of the result*"

Comment: The help page for `?system` suggests that you need to use either `shell` or `system2` when using Windoze. I'd also think to try `shQuote`.

Comment: Windows error 2 is file not found. Maybe not the same as had status 2.

Comment: I ran it with `shell` and got: `2: In shell(com) :
  'C:\SASLocal\RUN3614\56a8c11b-84b2-4af7-a155-01190936b1c1\M1_superGOtest.bat' execution failed with error code 2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows, to run batch files from command line you need to call a command line interpreter, Command Prompt or PowerShell, passing batch file as an argument.

A .bat script by itself is like an .R script and does not do anything until an executable runs it (i.e., *Rscript.exe, R.exe, Rcmd.exe, Rterm.exe*) and in this case, *cmd.exe* and *powershell.exe*:

```
# COMMAND PROMPT
system('cmd /c "C:\\SASLocal\\RUN3614\\56a8c11b-84b2-4af7-a155-01190936b1c1\\M1_superGOtest.bat"')

# POWERSHELL
system('powershell -c & "\'C:\\SASLocal\\RUN3614\\56a8c11b-84b2-4af7-a155-01190936b1c1\\M1_superGOtest.bat\'"')
```